# how i can set the "Allow this site to appear in search results?" for a site to be equal to No inside my event receiver

Tags: 2013, development, search, event-receivers, farm-solution

I am working on an item updated event receiver, and i want to set the "Allow this site to appear in search results?" for a site to No. now using the UI i can set it as follow:-

[image]

but i am note sure how i can do so using c# inside my event receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `NoCrawl` property of SPWeb to true.

The code would be as below:

```
web.NoCrawl=true;
web.Update();
```

Reference - [SPWeb.NoCrawl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.nocrawl.aspx)